# jqxGrid : Use filter with custom rendering

Tags: jqxgrid

I am new to jqxGrid and I am using custom rendering in a jqxGrid to have drop down lists inside a jqxGrid. 
This works well but when filtering with the standard filtering features of jqxGrid. it does not take into account what is displayed but the actual value (an id) of the column to filter.

The desired way of working would be to filter on what the user sees (e.g. the custom rendered values and not the data base ids).

Does anyone has a working example for this? or any ideas on how to implement it?

TIA